# Problem with columns in a newsletter template

Tags: two-column, multicol, columns

I am trying to use a ready-made template for a very simple publication. However, there is a problem with the columns in the document.

[Here is the template:](http://www.howtotex.com/templates/creating-a-latex-newsletter-template/)

And this is the newsletter that I'm trying to do. As you can see, there is a problem with the columns in the second page:

[image: columns problem]

Here is the code:

```
%%% LaTeX Template: Newsletter
%%%
%%% Source: http://www.howtotex.com/
%%% Feel free to distribute this template, but please keep the referal to HowToTeX.com.
%%% Date: September 2011


%%% ---------------
%%% PREAMBLE
%%% ---------------
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Define geometry (without using the geometry package)
\setlength\topmargin{-48pt}
\setlength\headheight{0pt}
\setlength\headsep{25pt}
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}
\setlength\textwidth{7.0in}
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-30pt}

\frenchspacing                      % better looking spacing

% Call packages we'll need
\usepackage[english]{babel}         % english
\usepackage{graphicx}               % images
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}        % math
\usepackage{multicol}               % three-column layout
\usepackage{url}                    % clickable links
\usepackage{marvosym}               % symbols
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % wrapping text around figures
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % font encoding
\usepackage{charter}                % Charter font for main content
\usepackage{blindtext}              % dummy text
\usepackage{datetime}               % custom date
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


    \newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\usepackage[pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
        colorlinks=false]{hyperref} % links and pdf behaviour

% Customize (header and) footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{ \footnotesize 
        Boletín de Miura 42\\
        \Mundus\ \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{HowToTeX.com}   \quad
        \Telefon\ 555-5555                                          \quad
        \Letter\ \href{mailto:frits@howtotex.com}{frits@howtotex.com}
      }
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize ~\\ Página \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}    % no bar on top of page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}    % bar on bottom of page

%%% ---------------
%%% DEFINITIONS
%%% ---------------

% Define separators
\newcommand{\HorRule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Creating a horizontal rule
\newcommand{\SepRule}{\noindent                          % Creating a separator
                        \begin{center}
                            \rule{250pt}{1pt}
                        \end{center}
                        }                       

% Define Title en News input
\newcommand{\JournalName}[1]{%
        \begin{center}  
            \Huge \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}
            #1%
        \end{center}    
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\JournalIssue}[1]{%
        \hfill \textsc{\mydate \today, No #1}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsItem}[1]{%
        \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}   
        \large #1 \vspace{4pt}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsAuthor}[1]{%
            \hfill by \textsc{#1} \vspace{4pt}
            \par \normalfont}       


%%% ---------------
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
%%% ---------------
\begin{document}
% Title 
% -----
\JournalIssue{1}
\JournalName{Miura 42}
\noindent\HorRule{3pt} \\[-0.75\baselineskip]
\HorRule{1pt}
% -----

% Front article
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.75\linewidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.41\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
        \\  % this spacer is needed to make the text on the right fit OK
    \end{wrapfigure}

    \NewsItem{Una nueva E-zine}


TEXT

\end{minipage}
\end{center}
% -----


% Other news (1)
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \NewsItem{Sobre Miura 42}
    \NewsAuthor{Fulanito}

         TEXT
% -----

\vspace{1cm}
% Other news (2)
% -----
\NewsItem{Sobre el nombre (que desvela el misterio de la vida, el universo y todo         lo     demás)}


        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{elephant}
        \end{center}




\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \NewsItem{Calibratio}
    \NewsAuthor{Fulanito}


    TEXT

\end{multicols}
% -----
\end{document}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I just want to create a little bit longer newsletter than the original template, but I don't know how to fix the columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your MWE seems to miss a `\end{multicols}` somewhere...

Comment: You must be getting errors when you compile this. You have an open `multicols` environment at the end of the document, which will cause TeX to stop with an error.

Answer (score 2):

I have corrected your given MWE a little bit.  So I added a proper `\headheight` to get rid off the message a (original) `0pt` headheigth is too small.  I also added the missing `\end{muticolumn}` (see the both lines marked in the MWE with some `%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%`. I changed language to english because I do not know french and had an error (missing e-frensh).  Please change it back.  I used `\blindtext` and `\Blindtext` to create 3 pages for the newspager.  Do not forget and remove `[demo]` for package `graphicx`, I hadn't your images ...

Please test the following MWE (with current MiKTeX 2.9 no error messages nor warnings):

```
%%% LaTeX Template: Newsletter
%%%
%%% Source: http://www.howtotex.com/
%%% Feel free to distribute this template, but please keep the referal to HowToTeX.com.
%%% Date: September 2011


%%% ---------------
%%% PREAMBLE
%%% ---------------
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

% Define geometry (without using the geometry package)
\setlength\topmargin{-48pt}
\setlength\headheight{12pt}  %needed for header/footer
\setlength\headsep{25pt} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}
\setlength\textwidth{7.0in}
\setlength\textheight{9.5in}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-30pt}
\setlength\evensidemargin{-30pt}

\frenchspacing                      % better looking spacing

% Call packages we'll need
\usepackage[english]{babel}         % english
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}               % images %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}        % math
\usepackage{multicol}               % three-column layout
\usepackage{url}                    % clickable links
\usepackage{marvosym}               % symbols
\usepackage{wrapfig}                % wrapping text around figures
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % font encoding
\usepackage{charter}                % Charter font for main content
\usepackage{blindtext}              % dummy text
\usepackage{datetime}               % custom date
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}
\usepackage[pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
        colorlinks=false]{hyperref} % links and pdf behaviour

% Customize (header and) footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{ \footnotesize 
        Boletín de Miura 42\\
        \Mundus\ \href{http://www.howtotex.com}{HowToTeX.com}   \quad
        \Telefon\ 555-5555                                          \quad
        \Letter\ \href{mailto:frits@howtotex.com}{frits@howtotex.com}
      }
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize ~\\ Página \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}    % no bar on top of page
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}    % bar on bottom of page

%%% ---------------
%%% DEFINITIONS
%%% ---------------

% Define separators
\newcommand{\HorRule}[1]{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{#1}} % Creating a horizontal rule
\newcommand{\SepRule}{%
  \noindent                          % Creating a separator
    \begin{center}
      \rule{250pt}{1pt}
    \end{center}
}                       

% Define Title en News input
\newcommand{\JournalName}[1]{%
        \begin{center}  
            \Huge \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}
            #1%
        \end{center}    
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\JournalIssue}[1]{%
        \hfill \textsc{\mydate \today, No #1}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsItem}[1]{%
        \usefont{T1}{augie}{m}{n}   
        \large #1 \vspace{4pt}
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}

\newcommand{\NewsAuthor}[1]{%
            \hfill by \textsc{#1} \vspace{4pt}
            \par \normalfont}       


%%% ---------------
%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
%%% ---------------
\begin{document}
% Title 
% -----
\JournalIssue{1}
\JournalName{Miura 42}
\noindent\HorRule{3pt} \\[-0.75\baselineskip]
\HorRule{1pt}
% -----

% Front article
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
  \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.75\linewidth}
  \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.41\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=0.42\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
      \\  % this spacer is needed to make the text on the right fit OK
  \end{wrapfigure}

  \NewsItem{Una nueva E-zine}


  \blindtext

  \blindtext

\end{minipage}
\end{center}
% -----


% Other news (1)
% -----
\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{3} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \NewsItem{Sobre Miura 42}
    \NewsAuthor{Fulanito}

    \blindtext

    \blindtext
% -----

\vspace{1cm}
% Other news (2)
% -----
\NewsItem{Sobre el nombre (que desvela el misterio de la vida, el universo y todo         lo     demás)}

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{elephant}
  \end{center}

\end{multicols} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%missing%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\vspace{0.5cm}
    \SepRule
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \NewsItem{Calibratio}
    \NewsAuthor{Fulanito}

    \Blindtext

    \Blindtext

\end{multicols}
% -----
\end{document}
```